# VPN Client conflict between local IP and VPN IP subnets - Macos NAT layer as solution?

Tags: router, vpn, subnet

My office is setup with a few subnets. My runabout computer can typically connect to the office over an L2TP VPN connection (setup in the network tab of Macos System Preferences) and access all of the subnets. I recently went out of town and, to my surprise, the internet connection at my "remote office" has the same subnet as one of the subnets at my office. Therefore I couldn't reach devices on that particular subnet from my runabout Mac computer.

If I had a router with me I could have hidden my runabout computer behind a layer of NAT. I would have been able to access all of my subnets over my VPN connection. I had no need to reach any devices on the actual local network; I only needed to connect to the internet.

I'm wondering if there is a way to implement a NAT layer in my Mac computer such that it would act as if my machine was behind a router. This would mean that my network connection would appear as a different IP address than the one it actually has on the local network. I would be able to assign this virtual local subnet at will to avoid conflict with the remote VPN subnets so that all the traffic that is intended for the VPN would pass over the tunnel.

[This problem of local and VPN subnet conflict would appear to me to be a common problem. After all, every coffee shop and guest network has the potential to conflict with a VPN network address range and cause this kind of issue. But I've not found many comments and good solutions in my googling so far. Perhaps I'm thinking about it from the wrong angle?]